# Enhance SQL script to better handle more than one result from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I wrote a set of queries for work awhile back that identify records on a large number of tables that our Windows application has locked. I recently attempted to enhance them so that they also unlock the records identified.

My current implementation requires you to run the script repeatedly if there is more than one locked entry on any of the tables. It feels like there is a better way to do this, but my SQL skills are "advanced beginner." What would be a better implementation? (MS SQL Server 2005, 2008)

```
/* Unlock Remark table */
DECLARE @LockedRemarkID NCHAR(36)
SET @LockedRemarkID = (SELECT TOP 1 RemarkId -- Top 1 prevents failure if result set >1
                         FROM Remark
                        WHERE RemarkConsumerId = @ConsumerVar
                                 AND CurrentTransactionId IS NOT NULL)

UPDATE Remark
   SET CurrentTransactionId = NULL
 WHERE RemarkId = @LockedRemarkID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do all the updates in the same update script:

```
UPDATE 
  Remark
SET 
  CurrentTransactionId = NULL
WHERE 
  RemarkConsumerId = @ConsumerVar
  AND 
  CurrentTransactionId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I knew there was a better way to do this. Thanks for the elegant solution.

Comment: @e.inglewood if you keep this answer mark it as accepted in order to "close" it so it doesn't add up to the colossal unanswered queue ;)